# Android: How to override setAdapter() in AutoCompleteTextView?

Tags: java, android, inheritance

How do you override the void setAdapter(T adapter) method for AutoCompleteTextView?

```
class CustomAutoCompleteTextView extends AutoCompleteTextView {

    //constructors

    @Override
    public void setAdapter(??? adapter) {
        super.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

I referenced [the android dev page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#setAdapter(T)) for the method signature, but was confused at the generic T. Earlier in the page, it says "T extends ListAdapter & Filterable". I'm not sure how to translate this into the Override signature. I also checked some previous stackoverflow questions (one about a ListView adapter), but it didn't help.

A solution would be nice, but also an explanation on what is going on would also be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: what you need that for? your method adds nothing

Comment: what do you want to achieve by overriding `setAdapter` method?

Comment: I am adding a DataSetObserver to the adapter whenever an adapter is added to the ACTV. The code I included doesn't include the code that I have since implemented. My initial question was less about ACTVs, and more about override methods with generic parameters.

Comment: oh i see, but shouldn't you override `BaseAdapter#registerDataSetObserver` in that case?

Comment: I don't think so. The goal is:
Whenever you add an adapter to my ACTV, add a specific DataSetObserver.I have since finished this and moved on, and my code works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I think I just figured it out. Go figure, right when you go for help. Here is my answer:

```
@Override
public <T extends ListAdapter & Filterable> void setAdapter(T adapter) {
    super.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Turns out you need to specify that class T (I was getting 'unresolved class T' before).